# Implementing MQTT using ESP-IDF and GoogleCloudPlataform (pub / sub)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, esp32, freertos

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I am trying to communicate my esp32 with google iot (pub / sub) using the native language of ESP-IDF. I'm using this framework https://github.com/espressif/esp-google-iot. I can connect to wifi, I put all the necessary informations: **project_id**, **location_id**, **registry_id**, **device_id**, **private_key.pem**.

The private_key.pem is on the directory: `...\examples\smart_outlet\main\certs`, however I have two private keys, the first starts with `----begin----have 2 line ----end----` and the other is similar to this format `d4:5z:sq:2A:sg:0s:u8:99:az.`

When the program tries to create JWT, it displays this error `APP: iotc_create_iotcore_jwt returned with error: 71.`
I researched and found error 71 in the iotc_error.h library: `@cond Numeric code: 71 * / IOTC_JWT_FORMATTION_ERROR.`

file iotc_jwt.c:

```
iotc_state_t iotc_create_iotcore_jwt(
    const char* project_id, uint32_t expiration_period_sec,
    const iotc_crypto_key_data_t* private_key_data, char* dst_jwt_buf,
    size_t dst_jwt_buf_len, size_t* bytes_written) {
  if (NULL == project_id || NULL == private_key_data || NULL == dst_jwt_buf ||
      NULL == bytes_written) {
    return IOTC_INVALID_PARAMETER;
  }and the program returns IOTC_INVALID_PARAMETER as an error.
```

now in the main program I include iotc_jwt.c, and call the certificate as shown below

```
extern const uint8_t ec_pv_key_start [] asm ("_ binary_private_key_pem_start");
extern const uint8_t ec_pv_key_end [] asm ("_ binary_private_key_pem_end");
```

Now I start task of defining the mqtt parameters

```
static void mqtt_task (void * pvParameters)
{
/ * Format the key type descriptors so that the customer understands
     what type of key is being represented. In this case, PEM encoded
     byte array of an ES256 key. * /
    iotc_crypto_key_data_t iotc_connect_private_key_data;
    
    iotc_connect_private_key_data.crypto_key_signature_algorithm = IOTC_CRYPTO_KEY_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM_ES256;
    iotc_connect_private_key_data.crypto_key_union_type = IOTC_CRYPTO_KEY_UNION_TYPE_PEM;
    iotc_connect_private_key_data.crypto_key_union.key_pem.key = (char *) ec_pv_key_start;
```

finally creation of the JWT

```
/ * Generate the client authentication JWT, which will serve as the MQTT
     * password. * /
    char jwt [IOTC_JWT_SIZE] = {0};
                                         
    printf ("creating JWT");
    size_t bytes_written = 0;
    iotc_state_t state = iotc_create_iotcore_jwt (CONFIG_GIOT_PROJECT_ID,
                            / * jwt_expiration_period_sec = * / 3600, & iotc_connect_private_key_data, jwt,
                             IOTC_JWT_SIZE, & bytes_written);
    if (IOTC_STATE_OK! = state) {
       ESP_LOGI (TAG, "iotc_create_iotcore_jwt returned with error:% ul", state);
        vTaskDelete (NULL);
    }
```

My question is: is the program code incorrect somewhere? or am I putting the wrong certificate and is it affecting the creation of the **JWT**? if so, what would be the correct model of the certificate?

I think the problem is in the call from the certificate to the main program, because I have already tested both examples of certificates and it didn't work, after that

If someone made this communication, can help me? I believe that other people are having the same problem.

I already made this communication on arduino and it worked, I managed to publish it in the IOT core, persisted this data in a function and stored it in firebase database realtime. but I need to do it on **IDF-ESPRESSIF**.

**PROBLEM SOLVED HERE**

The problem was in the certificate, I was generating a *public* and a *private* *key*, but I was just receiving the *public* *key*, so I used the following commands in the **cloud shell terminal** to solve my problem

first I generated the *private* *key* again:

`openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out ec_private.pem`

then the *public* *key*:

```
openssl ec -in ec_private.pem -pubout -out ec_public.pem
```

they were created now you need to receive them, that was my problem I just called the *public* *key* with the following command: `cat ec_public.pem`

but the key I needed was private so I used this command `cat ec_private.pem` and received the key I copied it and pasted it into the directory

`...\esp-google-iot\examples\smart_outlet\main\certs\private_key.pem`

I did this and my problem was solved.

Reference from https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/keys

Thank you!

att, Augusto

Comment: According to [this link](https://github.com/espressif/esp-google-iot/issues/9), your problem can be the key format. Besides, update the question by putting the code you are using for others analyse and try to help you. The part you put is too small.

Comment: Hi Dalton, thanks for your reply, so I had already seen this link, tested it with that example "----begin---- ----end----" certified but it still shows error 71, I edited the publication with more lines of code if it helps to better understand my problem.

Comment: Your `iotc_jwt.c` code seems to be still incomplete...

Comment: My`iotc_jwt.c` is the same as this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/blob/e140ef95c7f1c5d065b73edc2fd7b8ed5999dde8/src/libiotc/iotc_jwt.c)

Comment: I have posted how you resolved your issue as [community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), once you reach the 15 points of reputation, you will be able to [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the certificate, I was generating a public and a private key, but I was just receiving the public key, so I used the following commands in the cloud shell terminal to solve my problem

first I generated the private key again:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out ec_private.pem
```

then the public key:

```
openssl ec -in ec_private.pem -pubout -out ec_public.pem
```

they were created now you need to receive them, that was my problem I just called the public key with the following command: `cat ec_public.pem`

but the key I needed was private so I used this command `cat ec_private.pem` and received the key I copied it and pasted it into the directory

```
...\esp-google-iot\examples\smart_outlet\main\certs\private_key.pem
```

I did this and my problem was solved.

Reference from https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/keys